# Python: Generating YYMM string between two dates

Tags: python

I am given start_year, end_year, start_month and end_month e.g.

```
start_year = 2005
end_year   = 2017
start_month = 3
end_month   = 2
```

I want to generate the following strings:
0503.mat, 0504.mat, 0505.mat, 0506.mat, 0507.mat, 0508.mat, 0509.mat, 0510.mat, 0511.mat, 0512.mat, 0601.mat, ..0612.mat,....., ...1701.mat, 1702.mat

i.e. combine the year and month and generate such combination for all months between given start year/month and end year/month

Edit:

.mat is repeating on all output

This is what I have tried so far:

```
k = 0
for yr in range( 2005, 2007 + 1 ):
    for mn in range( 1, 12 + 1 ):
        YYMM[k]    =   "{:02}{:02}.mat".format(yr % 100, mn) )
        k = k + 1
```

But obviously it will not cover all months if I start at month 3 in year 2005 and go on to month 7 in 2006

Comment: `.mat` is repeating on all outputs?

Comment: yes .mat is repeating on all output

Comment: alright...so what did u try so far?

Comment: I don't have a clue where to start with doing this efficiently. I have thought about using for loop but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: that is fine...but at least post your try...so your question does not get much down votes and flagged for closing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
start_year = 2005
end_year = 2007
start_month = 3
end_month = 2
yymm = [(yy, mm) for yy in range(start_year, end_year + 1) for mm in range(1, 13)
        if (start_year, start_month) <= (yy, mm) <= (end_year, end_month)]
```

This generates a list of tuples

```
[(2005, 3), (2005, 4), (2005, 5), (2005, 6), (2005, 7), (2005, 8),
 (2005, 9), (2005, 10), (2005, 11), (2005, 12), (2006, 1), (2006, 2),
 (2006, 3), (2006, 4), (2006, 5), (2006, 6), (2006, 7), (2006, 8),
 (2006, 9), (2006, 10), (2006, 11), (2006, 12), (2007, 1), (2007, 2)]
```

I will leave the string formatting to you.

How it works: we are taking advantage of Python's mechanism for tuple comparison. When comparing `(x1, x2, ... xn)` and `(y1, y2, ... yn)`, the ordering is determined by `x1` and `y1` if they are not equal, and if they are, then by `x2` and `y2` if they are not equal, ... and so on.

EDIT:
To generate strings, you want to use list-comp as well: faster, and often cleaner than `for` loop:

```
formatted_yymm = ['{:>02}{:>02}.mat'.format(yy % 100, mm) for yy, mm in yymm]
```

Result:

```
['0503.mat', '0504.mat', '0505.mat', '0506.mat', '0507.mat', '0508.mat',
 '0509.mat', '0510.mat', '0511.mat', '0512.mat', '0601.mat', '0602.mat',
 '0603.mat', '0604.mat', '0605.mat', '0606.mat', '0607.mat', '0608.mat',
 '0609.mat', '0610.mat', '0611.mat', '0612.mat', '0701.mat', '0702.mat']
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for combining the strings here as I am again thinking of writing a for loop to combine the elements of tuples.

Comment: Thanks would have never guessed that string manipulation code you created.

Answer (score 0):

This could be made faster, and potentially more readable, but let maths do the work:

```
>>> start = (start_year - 2000) * 12 + start_month
>>> end = (end_year - 2000) * 12 + end_month
>>> ["{:02d}{:02d}.mat".format(x // 12, x % 12) for x in range(start, end+1)]
```

**Abbreviated output**

```
['0503.mat', '0504.mat', '0505.mat', '0506.mat', ...
'1610.mat', '1611.mat', '1700.mat', '1701.mat', '1702.mat']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
strings = ["{}{}.mat".format(str(year - 2000).zfill(2), str(month).zfill(2)) \
           for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1) \
           for month in range(start_month, end_month + 1)]
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question. The months in solution above doesn't cover all months.

Comment: months range is from 1-12 cycle